# How can I automate mysqldump database backups in Windows Server 2012?

Tags: mysql, windows-server-2012, database-backups

I'm trying to get mysqldump to do backups to a .sql file automatically, I have being reading that I need to use *cron jobs* or *Windows Task Scheduler*; the problem is that I can't find anything online that shows me how to do it.

To do the backups I'm  using cmd with the following commands:

```
mysqldump --user username --password=123  databtable > backup.sql
```

This command works perfectly, it does create the .sql file but how do I automate it in such a way that it does the backup every certain time.

Hopefully you can help me and thank you so much!

Comment: This has got nothing to do with software development. You have your parameters, then just use any task scheduler to run that for you.

Comment: @Shadow How come database backups have nothing to do with Software development? you make it sound like it's impossible for those two things to coexist. Before you give me a -1 you should ask questions first.

Comment: Automating database backups has got nothing to do with software development. Using windows task scheduler is not programming.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the *schtasks* command in Windows.
Command syntax details are available here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772785(v=ws.10).aspx

You could also use the Task Scheduler application in Windows if you like GUIs:

1. Create a new basic task
2. Set the Trigger (run daily, weekly, etc)
3. Set the Action. (what program to run) Be sure to
   include only the executable in the Program field, and put the
   command arguments in the Add Arguments field.

You probably want to set your task to *'Run whether the user is logged on or not'*. This is achieved by modifying the task, and adjusting the Security Options on the General Tab of the task.

When troubleshooting your task, use the History tab for info regarding job failures.